# DB2 Stored Procedure to (ALTER) RESTART the column with number

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis, db2, db2-400

I'm using SSIS packages to refresh my development tables with production data, using "Execute SQL Task" to run these queries:

```sql
alter table DEV.tablename alter column ID drop identity;
delete from DEV.tablename;
insert into DEV.tablename SELECT * FROM RESTORE.COVERAGE;
alter table DEV.tablename  alter column ID set generated always as identity;
alter table DEV.tablename  alter column ID restart with some_Integer_value;
```

I could not pass a number via parameters (some_Integer_value in above case) to [passing parameter in execute SQL task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtaZg.jpg)Execute SQL task(SSIS) so I had to use a stored procedure to run last ALTER table statement.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_incrementSP (IN TABLENAM VARCHAR(50),IN TABLECOLUM VARCHAR(30),IN INC_NUM INT)
    RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL

P1: BEGIN


    DECLARE STATEMENT1 VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE NAME VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE TABLENAME VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE TABLECOLUMN VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE INC_NUMBER INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    SET TABLENAME=TABLENAM;
    SET TABLECOLUMN=TABLECOLUM;
    SET INC_NUMBER=INC_NUM;
    -- Declare cursor



        SET STATEMENT1 = 'ALTER TABLE '||TABLENAME||' alter column '||TABLECOLUMN||' restart with'||INC_NUMBER||' ';

        PREPARE NAME FROM STATEMENT1;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STATEMENT1;
```

The stored procedure has been deployed successfully but when executing the stored procedure, I see this error:

> Run: DEV.SET_AUTO_INCREMENTSP(VARCHAR(50), VARCHAR(30), INTEGER)
>   {? = call DEV.SET_AUTO_INCREMENTSP(?,?,?)}
>   [SQL0104] Token  was not valid. Valid tokens: SET DROP RESTART.
>   Run of routine failed.
>    - Roll back completed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STATEMENT1 is 50 long, that's probably not enough, and you don't put any space between with and the number